# Magento2 internal pages redirecting 404 on nginx for multistores

Tags: nginx, magento2

We are trying to run multistore on NGINX:
example :
dev1.domain.com/en/ and dev2.domain.com/se/
for that we have created two folder en and se and copied index.php and nginx.conf files and changed code inside index.php according to store / website.

We have found that home page in each website calling perfectly but if we are trying to access internal page i.e product listing page, product detail page and cms page etc then site displaying 404 error, we have analyzed this issue and found that if we calling internal pages as mentioned above then its not referring index.php file of /en/ and /se/ folder its reading index.php of root folder that's why its redirecting on 404 in case of internal page.

Could anyone help to fix 404 issue for multistore setup on /en/ and /se/ domain and suggest what we are doing wrong here.
Please check the nginx.conf using the below link.
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T5rcYPJ6qzV73NigOffMNqsyfD7sg4l8/view

Comment: please show us your `nginx.conf`

Comment: Please check the nginx.conf:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T5rcYPJ6qzV73NigOffMNqsyfD7sg4l8/view

Comment: "created two folder en and se and copied index.php" - that's not how you run multistore. You have to use single filebase completely, and configure nginx with mapping of store codes to URLs/domains.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Thank you for your response. I have copied index.php(added store code as per magento) and default magento nginx.conf under /en  and /se. I have also created short links of magento app, pub,lib,var under these subdirectories. Also created virtual host  'dev1.domain.com' pointing to magento main installation outside of en and se. Home page is working fine and no issue. But when i ascess  product listing and other internal pages, it give 404. Let me know in which file i have to map store code to url/domain to fix this issue.

Comment: @Ali Once again: you don't do any tinkering with files (no copy any files/directories, not moving anything around) when deploying multistore).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this Ali? I'm facing the exact same issue

Comment: Have you find any solution @Ali